# Twitter Streaming API - filtering by urls

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to filter tweets from the Streaming API using a url in the track parameter. However I'm not getting the tweets I expect. My suspicion is that the filter doesn't apply to the expanded url and but to the automatically shortened url (t.co).

Can anyone confirm that this is the case? The [Streaming Api docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods) don't even mention how the filtering is applied.

If this is the case does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Could you provide what URL and query you are using

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the extended URL with cURL. I get the live tweets on my terminal for a particular search parameter. You may like to look into this one.

```
curl https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=SEARCH_PARAMETER -uUSERNAME:PASSWORD
```